# how to parse the json using alamofire in swift 2?

Tags: ios, json, swift2, nsdictionary, alamofire

I am having trouble with parsing json using alamofire (it is working fine  using browser or postman),below is my code

```
 Alamofire.request(.POST, reqStr.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())! , parameters: nil).responseJSON { response in
        GMDCircleLoader.hideFromView(self.view, animated: false)
        if let dict = response.result.value {
            self.selectArray = dict as! NSArray as! [NSDictionary]
            if self.selectArray.count == 0 {
            }else{
                self.selectProperty.hidden = false
            }
        }
    }
```

i am getting below error `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 14." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 14.}`
and searched a lot some body suggested that use `responseString` instead of `responseJSON`, if i use `responseString` i am getting data but in `string` format like

`"{"Properties":[{ "ID":"22", "post_title":"Test Property"  },{ "ID":"24", "post_title":"TestProperty"  }]}"`

how can convert it to `Dictionary` i used below code

```
if let dict = response.result.value 
        self.resulArray = dict as! [NSDictionary];
```

BUt it is crashing.
1)is their any way to get the results using `responseJSON`.
2) if i use responseString how to get convert to dictinary.
thanks in advance , I am new in Swift i am using swift2.0.

Comment: As the error says: the JSON is invalid. Instead of the value for key `Properties` – which is missing – there is a extraneous closing bracket. And don't do ugly things like `as! NSArray as! [NSDictionary]`

Comment: Why are you using http POST method?  Shouldn't it be GET

Comment: you mean from server end

Comment: even i am tried wit GET

Comment: Have you tried calling the url through a browser so you can verify you get json back?

Comment: @MartinMuldoon yes i tried like you said it is showing the results,in code showing error like i said above in question